# Background of box not changing color when responsive | HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: #6665ee;
}

.skill-bars{
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.skill-bars{
  background: black;

 }
}
.skill-bars .bar{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.skill-bars .bar:first-child{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.skill-bars .bar .info span{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes showText {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.skill-bars .bar .progress-line{
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,1) forwards;
}
@keyframes animate {
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
.bar .progress-line span{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: #6665ee;
  animation: animate 1s 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,1) forwards;
}
.bar .progress-line.html span{
  width: 90%;
}
.bar .progress-line.css span{
  width: 60%;
}
.bar .progress-line.jquery span{
  width: 85%;
}
.bar .progress-line.python span{
  width: 50%;
}
.bar .progress-line.mysql span{
  width: 75%;
}
.progress-line span::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
.progress-line span::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes showText2 {
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.progress-line.html span::after{
  content: "90%";
}
.progress-line.css span::after{
  content: "60%";
}
.progress-line.jquery span::after{
  content: "85%";
}
.progress-line.python span::after{
  content: "50%";
}
.progress-line.mysql span::after{
  content: "75%";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="skill-bars">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span>HTML</span>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line html">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span>CSS</span>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line css">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span>jQuery</span>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line jquery">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span>Python</span>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line python">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="info">
        <span>MySQL</span>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-line mysql">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So here for some reason, the background of the box turns black when you inspect the page and set it to responsive - **that is what I want** - but on my end, it does not work. Am I missing a reference link or something?

It does not work here: https://replit.com/join/wgghqoeseb-hussainomer1

What reference link do I seem to be missing? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the header

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

It helps the website position with the right viewport.

For more info checkout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

[image]